# Filter on child entity while fetching parent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want first child instead of whole child list while fetching the parent entity.
Based on updated date of child entity.

My Parent entity  :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "financial_aid_request_table")
public class FinancialAidRequestEntity extends BaseAuditingEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy= "financialAidRequest")
    private List<FARWorkFlowHistoryEntity> farWorkFlowHistory;

}
```

My child Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "far_workflow_history_table")
    public class FARWorkFlowHistoryEntity extends BaseAuditingEntity {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Column(name = "far_workflow_history_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Integer farWorkflowHistoryId;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "financialAidRequestId")
        private FinancialAidRequestEntity financialAidRequest;
        @Column(name = "updated_date")
        @NotNull(message = "Update date is mandatory")
        private Timestamp updatedDate;

    }
```

Repository :

```
public interface FinancialAidRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<FinancialAidRequestEntity, Integer> {


    List<FinancialAidRequestEntity> findTopByOrderByFarWorkFlowHistoryUpdatedDateDesc(Integer schoolId);
}
```

While executing this I am getting the following run time error :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

I am using spring boot with JPA and pgsql database.
Is there any way to do filtration in this way?
Your help would really be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the table **far_workflow_history_table** has not field **FarWorkFlowHistoryUpdatedDate**

Comment: I am fetching parent entity and I want to filter on child entity so I have passed like <childentity><fieldname> means FarWorkFlowHistoryUpdatedDate .

Comment: try to change the fetch :
`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy= "financialAidRequest")
    private List<FARWorkFlowHistoryEntity> farWorkFlowHistory;`

to

`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy= "financialAidRequest")
    private List<FARWorkFlowHistoryEntity> farWorkFlowHistory;`

Comment: Hey I have changed the code as per your suggestion but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by following code in parent entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "financial_aid_request_table")
public class FinancialAidRequestEntity extends BaseAuditingEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy= "financialAidRequest")
    private List<FARWorkFlowHistoryEntity> farWorkFlowHistory;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("(" +
        "SELECT h.far_workflow_history_id " +
        "FROM tten_farservice_far_workflow_history_table h " +
        "WHERE h.financial_aid_request_id = id " +
        "ORDER BY h.updated_date DESC " +
        "LIMIT 1" +
    ")")
    private FARWorkFlowHistoryEntity latestHistory;

}
```

Hope this answer will help others.